# Symfony2 remeber me working with only admin role

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

my problem with symfony2 is remember me working only with admin users else no cookie set.

when i call get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) in security controller it return false

```
        main:
        remember_me:
            key:  "%secret%"
            lifetime: 31536000 
            path:    /
            domain:   ~                                 
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            remember_me: true
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            default_target_path: /
            failure_path: /
            login_path: /
        logout:
            target: /
        anonymous:    true
```

Answer (score 0):

1. check the configuration

firewalls:

```
main:
    remember_me:
        key:      "%secret%"
        lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
        path:     /
        domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
        always_remember_me: true
    secured_area:
         pattern:    ^/
         anonymous: ~
         form_login:
             login_path:  login
             check_path:  login_check
             remember_me: true 
         logout:
             path:   /logout
             target: /
```

2. clear cache

Comment: i think the remember me configuration is correct bcoz it working when i try to login with admin privilege account to the system backend.